# Visual Studio: How to open .settings file by default with xml editor

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, settings

I have a xml file with configuration data for my application. This file is not used by the compiler but is copied into the output directory and is used during run time.

I want to name this file `extensions.settings`. But with the ending `.settings` visual studio treats the file in a special way. When opening the file by double click, visual studio always creates a `extension.Designer.cs`file and provides a specialiced editor for settings.

Does anybody how to prevent visual studio from creating the designer file? I just want to open the file as an xml.

Comment: Rename it to extensions.settings.xml

Comment: In addition to @andy's suggestion, or another way: Right click --> Open with... --> XML (Text) Editor

Comment: @andi: Its an convention in our company to name settings files with the ending `.settings`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL: as a habit, it often happens, that I double click the file. If there is a possibility to prevent the behaviour it would be nice.

Comment: If you keep it as .settings definitely it will open with VS only... So better rename it physically.

Comment: @scher After you click 'Open with...' there is an option, 'Set as Default'. I don't know if it only opens all files of that type using XML text editor by default or all files, as I have never used it.

Answer (score 2):

For explorer
Right click File > Open with > Select your XML editor > Check "Always use this app to open .settings file" done

For Visual studio Right click File > click "open with.." > select your XML editor > click Set as Default button

[how to change the default open app](http://www.howtogeek.com/237512/how-to-change-the-default-pdf-reader-in-windows-10/)

Comment: I asked for opening inside visual studio, not in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

- Like Keyur PATEL stated it can be done by:
  Right click on the file -> `Open With...`, select `XML (Text) Editor` and press the button on the right `Set as Default`.
- Another way is to open the options in Visual Studio via the menu `Tools` -> `Options...`. There go to the `Text Editor` -> `File Extension`settings page and add for the extension `settings` the `XML (Text) Editor`.